# Python make reading a Excel file faster

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I made a script that reads an Excel document en checks if the first row contains "UPDATED". If so it writes the whole row to another Excel document with the same Tab name.

My Excel document is 23 sheets with 1000 lines on each sheet, and now it takes more than 15 minutes to complete this. Is there a way to speed this up?

I was thinking about multithreading or multiprocessing but i don't know which one is better.

**UPDATE: the fact that my program took 15 minutes to run was al caused by the READ-ONLY mode, when i removed it, it only took 2 seconds to run the program**

```
import openpyxl
import os
from datetime import datetime

titles = ["Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5","Column6", "Column7", "Column8", "Column9", "Column10", "Column11", "Column12", "Column13", "Column14", "Column15", "Column16"]


def main():
    oldFilePath= os.getcwd() + "\oldFile.xlsx"
    newFilePath= os.getcwd() + "\newFile.xlsx"

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=oldFilePath, read_only=True)
    wb2 = openpyxl.Workbook()

    sheets = wb.get_sheet_names()
    sheets2 = wb2.get_sheet_names()

    #removes all sheets in newFile.xlsx
    for sheet in sheets2:
        temp = wb2.get_sheet_by_name(sheet)
        wb2.remove_sheet(temp)

    for tab in sheets:
        print("Sheet: " + str(tab))
        rowCounter = 2

        sheet = wb[tab]
        for row in range(sheet.max_row):
            if sheet.cell(row=row + 1, column=1).value == "": #if cell is empty stop reading
                break
            elif sheet.cell(row=row + 1, column=1).value == "UPDATED":
                if tab not in sheets2:
                    sheet2 = wb2.create_sheet(title=tab)
                    sheet2.append(titles)

                for x in range(1, 17):
                    sheet2.cell(row=rowCounter, column=x).value = sheet.cell(row=row + 1, column=x).value

                rowCounter += 1

                sheets2 = wb2.get_sheet_names()

    wb2.save(filename=newFilePath)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    startTime = datetime.now()
    main()
    print("Script finished in: " + str(datetime.now() - startTime))
```

Comment: give [xlrd](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd) a try.

Comment: If `xlrd` isn't helping, you can try to multiprocess the reading writing of the tabs.

Comment: Is it the reading or the writing part that's slow? (Comment out the writing part, time it, and compare.)

Comment: Also, "I was thinking about multithreading or multiprocessing but i don't know how to use it" means you should read a tutorial on it, not ask someone to basically write a new tutorial that won't be as good because it's off the top of their head and has to fit into an SO answer. For multiprocessing (and concurrent.futures), the stdlib docs actually have enough good examples that they might serve as their own tutorial; for threading, not so much.

Comment: I'm just going to up vote your post 'cause I think it's cute that *'23 sheets with 1000 lines on each sheet'* is *'very big'*.

Comment: give pypy a try

Comment: The reading takes a lot of time, because there are only like 30 rows that needs to be written to the new file

Comment: Is it better to use multithreading or multiprocessing?

Comment: Try using pandas function, read_excel()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such small workbooks there is no need to use read-only mode and by using it injudiciously you are causing the problem yourself. Every call to `ws.cell()` will force openpyxl to parse the worksheet again.

So, either you stop using read-only mode, or use `ws.iter_rows()` as I advised on your previous question.

In general, if you think something is running slow you should always profile it rather than just trying somethng out and hoping for the best.

Comment: Woow thanks! When i removed the read-only mode it went back from 15 minutes to 2 seconds. Can you explain that to me?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at some great multiprocessing tutorials, e.g.:
https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2016/08/02/python-201-a-multiprocessing-tutorial/

Also, the Python documentation will give you some great examples:
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html

You should give special attention to topics like using Pools and Queues.

Multiprocessing will help you get around the limitations of the Global Interpreter Lock, so that might be a good way to improve your performance.

Tuning the performance of I/O processes can be a tricky topic, so you'll need to find out more details about the bottleneck. If you can't improve its performance, you might try to find an alternative way to getting the same data.