# Is there a better way for processing a big excel with python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I'm trying to process a "big" set of data. It is an excel sheet with 5k rows and 30 columns. Most of the data stored in the cells are strings. What I have to do is to perform simple tasks on this data, such as:

Number of repetitions of a string

Checking some rules that should follow the data in the same row (only a few if's are needed to check it)

And so on...

My first attempt was to create 5k objects (1 per row), charge the data in them and then start running the tests. But saving the data in these objects took something like an hour for only 1k rows. I did this in python with the module openpyexcel with the read only mode.

My question is... is there a faster way to do this?

**THE ANSWER TO MY QUESTION WAS HERE**
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49400498/python-make-reading-a-excel-file-faster)

Comment: We need more details. Could you elaborate on specifically what objects you created, one per row? Ideally, please post some example data, your expected output, and your attempts at a solution. Pandas makes it easy to read an Excel file into memory as a DataFrame object, process it as needed, and write the result back to Excel format. 5000 by 30 is a manageable amount of data, but maybe your processing needs are very intense.

Comment: Pandas would be good options, also I found this package https://pytubes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers my problem was rather simple, I was missusing the "read-only option". This was making the program run slower now it takes 1.5 seconds to charge all the data in the memory